# I am adding UILabels into the cells of a UITableView. But when I am adding another data to the same label it's getting overwritten

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift

The problem is that when in my programme I have to change the datas in that UILabels inside each cells. But when I tried changing it, the datas are getting over written. I can't remove the previously created labels from the contentview. I am working in Swift.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: are you using CustomCell ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating those labels in code not in interface builder. You need to delete previous label before creating new one.
Better way of doing this is to do it in interface builder, subclass UITableViewCell, use your custom cell, drop a label in it, connect outlet and just override label data.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [link](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/21/designing-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-interface-builder/). It will shows how to add UILabel in a custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand your problem. You must using reusable cell technique and you are creating your label every time. I don't know the syntax of Swift so showing you in Objective-C. Hope you can convert it into Swift.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *myLabel = (UILable *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1];

if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
    [myLabel setTag:1];
}

[myLabel setText:@"your text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the following method in your Cell.m to solve problem.

```
- (void) prepareForReuse {
    NSLog(@"prep for reuse");
    // set your lable to nil here
}
```